# Android POST JSON Array to Server

Tags: android, json

I am having problems trying to POST a JSON Array.

For my Android code, I pass the JSON Array into the server by doing:

```
interests = // JSONArray of JSONObjects
final ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PARAM_USERNAME, username));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PARAM_INTERESTS, interests.toString()));

HttpEntity entity =  new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);
final HttpPost post = new HttpPost(UPDATE_INTERESTS_URI);
post.setEntity(entity);

// POST data to server
```

But when I read it from the server using:

```
$interests = $_POST["interests"];
echo $interets
```

It looks like `[{\"a\":\"1\"},{\"b\":\"2\"}]` instead of `[{"a":"1"},{"b":"2"}]`. The first one won't decode properly, and the second one works.

So why is it not working?

EDIT:
When I look at on Android before it posts, the JSONArray.toString() looks like `[{"a":"1"},{"b":"2"}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about android, but that looks like the `magic quotes`-feature of PHP is adding those slashes, if that's the case you could use this on server-side:

```
$interests = $_POST["interests"];
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $interests = stripslashes($interests);
}
echo $interests;
```

Answer (score 1):

do it in this way:

```
JSONObject paramInput = new JSONObject();
paramInput.put(PARAM_USERNAME, username);
paramInput.put(INTERESTS, interests.toString());
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(paramInput.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
```

Comment: But would I have to change anything on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
StringEntity params = new StringEntity("your_Data");
```

instead of your UrlEncodedEntity.